# About the roots of the derivative of a polynomial.

Tags: complex-analysis, polynomials

Suppose $p(z)=\prod_{k=1}^{n}(z-\lambda_k)^{m_k}$, and $\lambda_k\in H=\{z\in \mathbb C\mid \operatorname{Im}(\frac{z-a}{b})\geq 0\}$, where $a\in \mathbb C$ and $b\neq 0$ in $\mathbb C$. Show the roots of $p'$ are in $H$.

Comment: Your definition of the set $H$ is incomplete as $a,b$ are not specified.

Comment: It is well defined. This is a semi-plan in $\mathbb R^2$.

Comment: They are fixed complex numbers.

Comment: When $a=0, b=1$ this semi-plane is one above the real axis. And when $a=0, b=-1$, it would be the semi-plane below the real axis. Unless you specify $a,b$  one would not know what to do. Possibly $a,b$ are related in a specific way to the polynomial $p(z)$. You are omitting something.

Comment: No, I'm not omitting anything. This is the way the question is given in my book Análise Complexa, from the author Alcides Lins, IMPA Press.

Comment: It's true for any value of $a$ and $b$, provided $b\not=0$. See my proof.

Comment: @PVanchinathan: $a$ and $b$ cannot be anything, should be chosen so that the semi-plane contains all roots of the polynomial.

Comment: Thanks enzotib, I was wondering if my simple objection is so difficult to understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Observe that $H$ is a convex set: if $z_1,z_2\in H$ then for any $t\in (0,1)$, we must also have $z_1 t + z_2 (1-t)\in H$. Since the roots of the derivative of a polynomial can be expressed as convex combinations of the roots of the polynomial, it follows that the roots of $p'(z)$ also lie in $H$.

---

**Proof that the roots of $p'(z)$ are convex combinations of the roots of $p(z)$:**

Let $\{r_i\}_{i=1}^n$ denote the (complex) roots of $p(z)$, counted with multiplicity. Then $p(z)=a\prod (z-r_i)$ for some $a\not=0$. We compute that
$$
\begin{align*}
\frac{p'(z)}{p(z)}&=\frac{d}{dz}\log p(z)\\
&=\frac{d}{dz}\left[\log a +\log (z-r_1)+\ldots + \log(z-r_n)\right]\\
&=\frac{1}{z-r_1}+\ldots + \frac{1}{z-r_n}.
\end{align*}
$$

Let $r$ be any root of $p'(z)$ which is not a root of $p(z)$. Then
$$
0=\frac{p'(r)}{p(r)},
$$
so by virtue of the previous calculation
$$
\begin{align*}
0&=\frac{1}{r-r_1}+\ldots + \frac{1}{r-r_n}\\
\implies 0&=\sum_{i}\frac{r-r_i}{|r-r_i|^2}=\sum_i \alpha_i (r-r_i),
\end{align*}
$$
where each $\alpha_i=\frac{1}{|r-r_i|^2}$ is a positive constant. Rearranging the last equation gives
$$
r=\sum_i \left(\frac{\alpha_i}{\sum_i \alpha_i}\right)r_i,
$$
which shows that $r$ is a convex combination of $\{r_i\}$. This proves the theorem.

Comment: Let me see, your saying something that $\frac{r-r_i}{|r-r_i|^2}=\frac{1}{r-r_i}$???Why?

Comment: No, I'm not saying that. Read that step carefully. Are you familiar with how to simplify fractions involving complex numbers?

Comment: Can you clarify that step for me?

Comment: Suppose $a$ is a complex number and consider the fraction $1/a$. If I want to get rid of the imaginary numbers which appear in the denominator, I can multiply the top and bottom by $\bar{a}$ to get $\frac{\bar{a}}{a\bar{a}}=\frac{\bar{a}}{|a|^2}$.

Comment: But the numerator will continue be as our $r-r_i$ after we pass the conjugate? Is this step right?

Comment: Yes after you simplify the fractions, take complex conjugates of both sides...

Comment: Sorry for my insistense, but those things (Complex Analysis Argument) aren't so clear to me yet.

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot.